# How to Display User Chats using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote this query To fetch details but its not working. Here is my Code:

```
$sender_id=$_GET['sender_id'];
$sender_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$sender_id);
$sender_id=htmlentities($sender_id);
$sql1="SELECT * FROM massges where receiver_id='".$_SESSION['u_id']."' and sender_id='".$sender_id."' order by msg_id";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM massges where receiver_id='".$sender_id."' and sender_id='".$_SESSION['u_id']."' order by msg_id";
$sqls=[$sql1,$sql2];

foreach($sqls as $k => $sql){

$run=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {

  $msg_text=$row['msg_text'];
  $msg_id=$row['msg_id'];

$query1="SELECT * FROM users where u_id='".$sender_id."'";

$query2="SELECT * FROM users where  u_id='".$_SESSION['u_id']."'";

$querys=[$query1,$query2];

foreach($querys as $k => $query){

$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

  $user_image=$data['user_image'];

}
echo '<br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s2" style="margin: 0px;">
      <img src="users/'.$user_image.'" class="circle right" height="20px">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6"><span class=" blue lighten white-text" style="margin: 0px;border-radius: 10px;padding:5px;">'.$msg_text.'<span></div>
  </div>';}
```

Here is the displayed data: 
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cJ2K.png)

How can I display sender's and receiver's messages?

Comment: If that `$sender_id` variable is user provided or user can alter it (URL parameter for example) your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: There are a number of problems with this code, not the least that you are using unsanitized data in your queries.  This allows for a SQL injection attack.  But also, your are running your queries sequentially, so that all of the sender's messages will be listed before all of the receiver's messages.  You want them to alternate, according to timestamp, not user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in one query, your code will be much easier to debug if you do so:

```
$sender_id = $_GET['sender_id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];

// Get all Messages where the user and sender are involved
$statement = $con->prepare('
    SELECT
        messages.msg_text,
        users.user_image
    FROM
        messages
    JOIN
        users ON users.u_id = messages.sender_id
    WHERE
        (
            messages.sender_id = ?
            AND messages.receiver_id = ?
        ) OR (
            messages.sender_id = ?
            AND messages.receiver_id = ?
        )
    ORDER BY
        messages.msg_id
');

$statement->bind_param(
    "iiii",
    $sender_id,
    $user_id,
    $user_id,
    $sender_id
);

$statement->execute();

// Assign the content of 'msg_text' and 'user_image'
$statement->bind_result($text, $image);

// loop through all results
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    /* ECHO YOUR HTML HERE */
    echo $text;
    echo $image;
}
```

Links that may help:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\HKK\users\msg.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HKK\users\msg.php on line 32

I Got This Error

Comment: use `$con = new mysqli(host, user, pass, db)` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: forgot the execute my bad. added it

Comment: No its Showing same Error

Comment: in this case there is an error in the sql i wrote, try dumping the error: `var_dump($statement->error);` after prepare

Comment: Sql looks good to me, but i may have named a field wrong: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7324b1/1/0

Comment: Thanks I Got it Many Many Thanks

Comment: Have i been missing something? Share your results please :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sender_id = $_GET['sender_id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
$sql="SELECT
    massges.msg_text,
    massges.msg_id,
    users.user_image
FROM
    massges
JOIN
    users ON users.u_id = massges.sender_id
WHERE
    (
        massges.sender_id = '".$sender_id."'
        AND massges.receiver_id = '".$user_id."'
    ) OR (
        massges.sender_id = '".$user_id."'
        AND massges.receiver_id = '".$sender_id."'
    )
ORDER BY
    massges.msg_id";
$run=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
  $msg_id=$row['msg_id'];
  $msg_text=$row['msg_text'];
  $user_image=$row['user_image'];

  echo '<br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s2" style="margin: 0px;">
      <img src="users/'.$user_image.'" class="circle right" height="20px">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6"><span class=" blue lighten white-text" style="margin: 0px;border-radius: 10px;padding:5px;">'.$msg_text.'<span></div>
  </div>'; }  }
```